# How to block a single integer input with pyinputplus method blockRegexes?

Tags: python, regex, input

```
import pyinputplus as pyip

response = pyip.inputNum(prompt='Input an number',
                         allowRegexes=[r'[I|V|X|L|C|D|M]', r'zero'],
                         blockRegexes=[r'([0-9]{1})'], limit=20, timeout=30)

print(response)
```

I can't quite understand what the regular expression should be so that it blocks a single digit integer input. This code blocks any kind of integer input. This also allows inputs such as "M1", even though in allowRegexes I wanted to allow Roman numerals to be accepted, not mixes of Roman and Arabic numerals.

If anyone could help I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
response = pyip.inputNum(prompt='Input an number',
                         allowRegexes=[r'^[IVXLCDM]+$'],
                         blockRegexes=[r'^\d$'],
                         limit=20, timeout=30)

print(response)
```

To improve the code I have added regex delimitors :
^ to start the expression and
$ to finish the expression.
So the regex ll be applied on all the line and not number after number which caused your code to accept single digit number.

Limitations : with this expression the invalid roman numeric expression is not checked.
IIX passes the test but is not a valid roman expression.